# Add Pear Package to php.ini for drupal

Tags: drupal, pear, php

I got nginx with php-fpm working and installed a pear package

```
$ pear install Mail_Mime
```

- but I can't seem to get it to load properly for a Drupal module. How should I include it in my php.ini file?

The pear extension is here: `/usr/local/lib/php/Mail/mimeDecode.php`

php.ini is currently set as:

```
include_path    =  ".:/usr/local/lib/php"
```

I'm not sure how to add the extension though so Drupal can catch it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The include path is correct. After changing php.ini, you need to restart your web server.
If it still does not work, follow http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php